# Mail rejected using phpmailer on GoDaddy.com host

Tags: phpmailer

Using this:

```
require("lib/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Username = "XXX@validGoDaddyAccount.com"; 
$mail->Password = "xxx";
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body= $message;
$mail->AddAddress($toAddr);
$mail->FromName = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"; 

$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   return true;
}
```

I get this response:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 p3plsmtpa07-05.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ESMTP 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-p3plsmtpa07-05.prod.phx3.secureserver.net hello     [00.00.0.0], secureserver.net 250-HELP 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN 250-SIZE 31457280 250-PIPELINING 250-8BITMIME 250 OK 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:550 User XXX has exceeded their send quota 
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 550 User XXX has exceeded their send quota 
The following From address failed: XXX : MAIL not accepted from server,550,User XXXm has exceeded their send quota 
SMTP server error: User XXX has exceeded their send quota 

Mailer Error: The following From address failed: XXX : MAIL not accepted from server,550,User XXX has exceeded their send quota 
SMTP server error: User XXX has exceeded their send quota
```

I know about setting the SMTP Relays for GoDaddy accounts and they are set right. I can send email from this account all day long as long as I don't use PHPmailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I needed to pre-authorize with POP prior to starting the SMTP operation:

```
require("lib/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once('lib/class.pop3.php');     
$pop = new POP3();
$pop->Authorise('pop.server.net', 110, 30, 'username', 'password', 1);
$mail = new PHPMailer();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

see the following line

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:550 User XXX has exceeded their send quota
```

That's why it is rejecting.

Comment: Doesn't get more obvious than that ;)

Comment: I would kindly refer you to the last line of my post:  "I can send email from this account all day long as I *don't* use PHPmailer." My issue is that I have _not_ exceeded my quota.